# How To Create Leaf Nodes And Then Build A Tree

Tags: java, tree, priority-queue

I have made a priority queue of integers in increasing order.

I now need to create a leaf node for each term in this priority queue in increasing order. Then, I need to use these leaf nodes to create a tree by taking the sum of the first two terms and replacing them with a leaf node that is their sum, and so on.

For example, if the leaf nodes are {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, then, since 1 + 2 = 3, the new set of leaf nodes should be {3, 3, 4, 5}, where 3 has left and right children 1 and two respectively. Then, since 3 + 3 + 6, the new set of leaf nodes should be {4, 5, 6}, where the 6 has left and right children 3 and 3 respectively. Then, since 4 + 5 = 9, the new set of leaf nodes should be {6, 9}, where 9 has left and right children 4 and 5 respectively. Then, since 6 + 9 = 15, the new set of leaf nodes should be {15}, where 15 has left and right children 6 and 9 respectively.

Please help me understand how to go about this in Java. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Java is an OOP language, meaning that you have to write a "recipes" (called classes) in order to create things (leaf Nodes, trees, anything...).

The standard ways of a tree are the following:

```
class Tree{

    class LeafNode{

        LeafNode children[];
        String data;        //data could be any Object or Generic

        LeafNode(int childrenNumber, String d){
            data = d;
            children = new LeafNode[childrenNumber];
        }
    }


  LeafNode root;

/*
 *  There can be the class Tree Constructor and put-get functions
 */

}
```

The leaf-sum idiom you mention can be implemented in the put method.

Comment: I see, but this is for an assignment where were are only turning in the class that we have to make for the assignment, so I am sure that there is a way for me to do this within that assignment. I already created the priority queue. I need to make each element a leafed node. Then, I need to make a binary tree using those leaf nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to write your `Leaf` class:

```
public class Leaf {

    public int value = 0;
    public Leaf left = null;
    public Leaf right = null;

    public Leaf(int value) {
    this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() {
    return "[" + value + ", left: " + left + ", right: " + right + "]";
    }
}
```

Then you have to implement your algorithm. Something like that should work:

```
static void doIt(List<Leaf> leaves) {

    if (leaves.size() == 1) {
        return;
    }
    Leaf head = leaves.get(0);
    Leaf next = leaves.get(1);
    Leaf sum = new Leaf(head.value + next.value);

    sum.left = head;
    sum.right = next;
    leaves.set(0, sum);
    leaves.remove(1);

    sortLeaves(leaves);
    doIt(leaves);
    }

    static void sortLeaves(List<Leaf> leaves) {
    Collections.sort(leaves, new Comparator<Leaf>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Leaf o1, Leaf o2) {
        return o1.value - o2.value;
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: I see, but this is for an assignment where were are only turning in the class that we have to make for the assignment, so I am sure that there is a way for me to do this within that assignment. I already created the priority queue. I need to make each element a leafed node. Then, I need to make a binary tree using those leaf nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I remember from data structures

```
public class Tree
{

    //constructors and stuff

    private class BSTNode<T>
    {
        //constructors and stuff

        private T data;
        private BSTNode<T> left, right;
    }


}
```

I remember with trees the node class was always a private inner class to a larger tree class. The logic to determine is something is a leaf could be something like this.

```
public boolean isLeaf()
{
    return (left == null) && (right == null);
}
```

If the node doesn't have any children then it is a leaf.

Comment: I see, but this is for an assignment where were are only turning in the class that we have to make for the assignment, so I am sure that there is a way for me to do this within that assignment. I already created the priority queue. I need to make each element a leafed node. Then, I need to make a binary tree using those leaf nodes.

Comment: @user3043437 The above class can be used to make a binary tree. You don't need to write a special class for leaf nodes. Your leaf nodes are just like regular. Both of their pointers are just set to null. It  seems like you don't completely understand what a binary tree is. You just make a binary tree with nodes. The leaves are just the ones at the end of the tree. Anyway, the class above is written using generics so you can make nodes of any object type.

Comment: Oooh Okay! Thanks! That makes a lot of sense and I completely understand now. Yeah, I have a math degree and am really good at logic, but I'm only been programming for about two months LOL.